Does Azure AD support custom HTTP Headers for SCIM User provisioning?
I am doing SCIM User Provisioning. For that I have developed SCIM APIs which supports client credentials authorization mode as well as long lived token in the form of API Key. When I was testing Azure AD SCIM Provisioning, I can see Azure supports long lived token only with Bearer prefix. But when Azure makes an API call to my application, I receive this token with Bearer prefix in Authorization header.
Is there a way we can use custom HTTP Header for SCIM user provisioning? Eg. Rather than Bearer prefix, does Azure support anyother custom prefix eg.MyAPP_TOKEN OR something else.
When Azure makes a call to provision user, I receive long lived token with Bearer prefix in Authorization header.
Is there is a way we can get some other prefix as well rather than Bearer ?

No. For custom non-gallery apps, custom headers are not supported, nor are authorization methods other than long-lived bearer tokens. Custom headers aren't (generally) supported for gallery apps either, but there are other available authorization methods.
